# Netbeans showing black box error '\u3000'

Tags: netbeans

Netbeans does not allow me to write in text editor. When I type is shows black box and says illegal character '\u3000'.
I thought it was because of "Insert" key but wasn't. Is there any solution to this problem. 
[image showing black box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6FCP.png)

Answer (score 0):

did you try to press "insert" button??
i had the same issue and it solved the problem.

Comment: Yes. I tried. But "insert" key did not work.
I got this issue two times and I have to close Netbeans both times because of this issue.